# ¿Cómo evitar que se valide un TextBox con sólo mayúsculas?

Tags: asp.net, validación, web

Tengo un TextBox en asp.net. Nos pidieron que evitemos que el usuario introduzca sólo mayúsculas y, en caso de que lo haga, que mande un mensaje de error tipo "*No puedes usar sólo mayúsculas*", y que no valide el TextBox.

¿Alguien lo ha hecho antes? ¿Podrían decirme cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la validación la estás haciendo en la parte de servidor, en C# puedes utilizar LINQ.

Ejemplo:

```
// Devuelve true si todos los caracteres en el string son mayúsculas
return "tuString".All(char.IsUpper);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo solucione usando un scrip en c#, agradezco que te tomaras el tiempo de responder.